# Assistance With Building Wireframe Section

Tags: html, css

Newcomer to StackOverflow. Heard a lot of good things about you guys. I'm on day 6 of my journey to becoming a front end developer and I am having a bit of trouble with coding the layout on the wireframe image I included in this post.

Specifically, I am having trouble with the whole section where `main navigation`, `promo #6`, new releases are. I've been stuck on this for the past 2 days. First I tried it without flexbox and failed. Today I tried it with flexbox and failed. I was going to try the grid tomorrow but figured I might as well come to ask here as I have asked on other sites but did not manage to do it even with their help.

I think I need to see the code at least once to know in the future how to deal with it. I have tried a variety of different methods using flexbox and without it. So if someone would be so kind as to help me out I would sincerely appreciate it.

Here is a link to my codepen so that you can see I did try at least. I think I'm close actually but I just need that final push.

```
[Codepen]
(https://codepen.io/Chizzah/pen/aboZyqL)
```

Link to imgur to see wireframe:

[image: image taken from https://m.imgur.com/a/i1LaSR6]

The reason I am trying to build this wireframe is that I would like to get my layout coding skills on point before going further with other things like more advanced styling and CSS simple animations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please put all the code in the question post and the specific issue you are facing. You can edit your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57540822/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current layout would suggest you are going the grid route because all of your child components are siblings within "container_3". The layout you are seeking is easily achievable with flexbox or grid. Considering you are looking to build your skills, I would suggest flex because it is easier to wrap your head around.

The only thing you are really missing here are additional containers within your parent container that will allow you to nest vertical elements inside them.

```
<div class="container_3">
  <div class="container_3__vertical-wrap">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_3__vertical-wrap">
    <div class="box4"></div>
    <div class="box5"></div>
    <div class="box6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_3__vertical-wrap">
    <div class="box7"></div>
    <div class="box8"></div>
    <div class="box9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the vertical-wraps, you will want "flex-flow: column" and you can size everything from there.

Comment: Hi Gumball! Thank you so much! That with some other information helped me to complete the task at hand. Your help was perfect!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark my answer correct and give it an upvote. Thanks!